# How to require a minimum text length in UITextField before enabling keyboard return key

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

In my app users register or login at a site that requires passwords at least 6 characters long. To work with that I'd like to impose that minimum in the password UITextField before the keyboard return button is enabled. Setting Auto-enable Return Key in the XIB causes the return key to be disabled until there is at least one character & (contrary to my expectations) turning that off causes the return key to be anabled even with no text.

Can anyone tell me how I can keep the return key disabled until the user has input 6 characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no apparent way to disable the return key until the user has entered 6 password characters. However, I have some other solutions for you that might serve the purpose.

1. Writing a small message below the password field -- "Must be at least 6 characters"
2. Showing alert when the password textfield loses focus.

> ```
> -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
>  {
>    if([password length] <6)
>       Show alert. On alert dismiss code block do this -->[password becomeFirstResponder]
>  // this takes the focus back to the password field after alert dismiss.
>  }
> ```

3. Showing alert when the user presses return key.

> ```
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
> {
>     if([password length] <6)
>     show alert like above.
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was pretty confident I'd looked hard enough, both in Apple's docs & here, to find the solution if it was possible. You've confirmed my fears & your alternative is along the lines I had in mind as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is with textFieldShouldEndEditing: and not textFieldDidEndEditing:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL shouldEnd = YES;

    if ([[textField text] length] < MINIMUM_LENGTH) {  
        shouldEnd = NO;
    }   

    return shouldEnd;
}
```

Comment: With respect, this does not do what was requested "impose that minimum in the password UITextField before the keyboard return button is enabled"

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method

textField.resignFirstResponder()
   if let txt = textField.text as? String {
      if(txt.length >= minimum){
         textField.endEditing(true)
      }
   }  
   return false 
}
```