# iOS User Interface without Storyboards: Change UITextField font and guarantee minimum characters for a textField Object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, swift3

I didn't find an answer that solved my problems or that was explained in an easy way. So please don't give me any other stack overflow links because I realy read them and couldn't solve my problem. I also looked up in the documentation. Thanks for helping me out.

Problem1:
Im building an iOS app with **SWIFT** and don't use storyboards for the user interfaces. I created a LoginController with the UItextfield userName where a new user can enter his userName (see below : userNameTextField ). I changed the placeholder text to the String "Name".

Question1: How can I change the placeholder font and  textsize. I want to have a **bold** placeholder text.

```
let userNameTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Name"
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tf

}()
```

Problem2:

Usernames must be at least five characters long before the registration can work. How can I guarantee this in my code. A kind of notification would be cool like Sorry you need at least 5 characters.
Can you please give me just a short example for one UiTextField Object ?

Thanks

Comment: Problem 2: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329631/how-to-require-a-minimum-text-length-in-uitextfield-before-enabling-keyboard-ret

Comment: Problem 1: Do you want to just change the placeholder font, or placeholder + text font?

Comment: Look at the attributedPlaceholder property of a UITextField. I'm pretty sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

```
tf.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

**Problem 2:**

[You can check this answer out on how to create a pop up message (UIAlertView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift)

Comment: Problem 2 see @kennytm's link